# How to find new client?

Tags: php, sql-server

I ran into one problem that I can not solve for 3 days already.
The problem is current, there is a database of two columns of date ("yyyy-mm") and the phone number is unique non-repeating. I want to find out how many new customers each month. Well, the formula is roughly current (the new client is the first month + the new client is the next month ....). If the customer meets the first month he is considered a new customer, then it is on the other month, he is missing a new customer.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Confusing statement:- `Well, the formula is roughly current (the new client is the first month + the new client is the next month ....). If the customer meets the first month he is considered a new customer, then it is on the other month, he is missing a new customer.`

Comment: Can you explain properly!

Comment: For example<br/>
2017-01 | 70004<br/>
2017-01 | 70003<br/>
2017-02 | 70004<br/>
2017-02 | 70003<br/>
2017-02 | 7,0005<br/>
 <br/>
First month 2 new customer on the second month 1 new customer

Comment: If you have something to add, use the `edit` link. Don't post examples or anything similar in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try Something like this:

```
select year(f2.DateColumn) YearCol,  month(f2.DateColumn) MonthCol, count(f2.PhoneNumber) NbNewPhone
from (
        Select f1.*,  row_number() over(partition by f1.PhoneNumber order by f1.DateColumn) rang
        from yourTable f1
) f2 
where f2.rang=1
group by year(f2.DateColumn),  month(f2.DateColumn)
order by 1, 2
```

or if you column is not a date :

```
select f2.DateColumn, count(f2.PhoneNumber) NbNewPhone
from (
        Select f1.*,  row_number() over(partition by f1.PhoneNumber order by f1.DateColumn) rang
        from yourTable f1
) f2 
where f2.rang=1
group by f2.DateColumn
order by 1, 2
```

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'by'.

Comment: you have an error? Have you change you column name?

Comment: DateColumn is a date or datetime column?

Comment: DateColumn - date.

Comment: Here is the error in my opinion=> row_number(partition by

Comment: Yes, I changed the names of the tables and columns

Answer (score 0):

As per your example just below count is sufficient:

```
Select DateColumn, Count(PhoneNumber) from yourTable
    Group by DateColumn
```

If Datecolumn is real date as yyyy-mm-dd with date datatype you can query as below:

```
Select year(datecolumn), month(datecolumn), count(PhoneNumber) from yourTable
   group by year(datecolumn), month(datecolumn)
```

Comment: Both examples did not help me get the right answer.

Comment: You might require to provide sample input dataset and expected output... As per your example above first query will return the counts...